# Outlook 2007: how to search (filter) content of a search folder?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, search, microsoft-outlook-2007

I'm using `MS Outlook 2007` and I'm often working with search folders which show me a subset of all messages based on certain criteria.

I have a search folder which lists all emails which are in my sent and inbox folders (and excludes some with a certain category from the view).

When I'm searching for mails about a certain topic in this folder and type a word in the search box right above the mails, the search result also shows mails which were not shown in the original search folder.

[image]

Is there a way to limit this search to the contents of the active search folder?

#### Background history

For example, my goal is to have **Inbox Zero** and **"Outbox Zero"** which means, that I extract all tasks or notes from all messages I have received or sent to another task management systems and then move those mails to an archive folder (so ideally my inbox and sent folder are empty).

In reality, in very busy times there pile a lot of mails (up to 200) in those directories and then it gets difficult for me to look through them or find those with important topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the answer was simple.

- Click on the down arrow next to the search box
- Select "Search options"
  (this is translated from my german GUI, the English Menu names could
  be different)

  - Select the radio button "only active folder" (or similar) at the bottom

In my `Outlook` the selection was "all folders" which explains that the search was always carried out in all folders
[image]